# ERROR in bundle.js from UglifyJs Name expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, uglifyjs

I am trying to use **UglifyJS** to minimize/compress my `bundle.js` file. When I run `webpack -p`, I am getting the following:

`ERROR in bundle.js from UglifyJs
Name expected [bundle.js:105519,6]`

Line 105519 is as follows:

`const {M, l, pattern} = __webpack_require__(862)`.

I am using React w/ ES6. Any thoughts as to what is wrong?

Comment: I feel like I've seen this in gulp-land before, psure the solution was to transpile everything first then run uglify on the results of the transpile.

Answer (score 23):

Every version of Webpack has a built-in version of UglifyJS (0.4.6) which doesn't support ES6. This version supports ES5 syntax only.

There are two possible solutions:

- Make transpiler target `es5`
- Don't use the built-in version of `uglifyjs-webpack-plugin` and install [the latest version](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin) using `npm install -D uglifyjs-webpack-plugin`. Add it to your `plugins` property in your configuration:

  ```
  const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin')

  module.exports = {
    plugins: [
      new UglifyJSPlugin()
    ]
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This error comes when [uglifyjs-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin) is not able to **Uglify** particular dependency

> **So, How to find library that creates such error ?**

I was using react , so i deleted all forms in my app and kept just 1 form and imported all dependencies in it, and **remove/add** those dependencies one by one
and run command

```
webpack -p
```

**SO** In My case it was [browser-history](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-history) creating such error .Now you can report this issue to that library's author with some **replicating example**

[working Package.json & .babelrc](https://gist.github.com/pawarvijay/dcf5fb1ec33350f32ebcf9f0cfb35286)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely an issue with the version of uglifyjs and the javascript target you are trying to compile to. It could be 2 things, your webpack setup and your babel setup causing this.

If you are using the latest version of [webpack v3.5.5](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/v3.5.5) it comes with [uglifyjs-webpack-plugin ^0.4.6](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/tree/v0.4.6) which doesn't support a target of es6 or above.

Referring to the current Webpack [docs](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/) about [UglifyjsWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/) options it covers how to use the latest beta version of [uglify-js-webpack-plugin v1.0.0-beta.2](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/tree/v1.0.0-beta.2). But isnt that clear on how to install that version.

To use it with the Webpack do

`yarn add uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@beta --dev`

As you don't mention what your Babel setup is. You might be or want to use [`babel-preset-env`](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-env/) as your preset. There is an [option for uglifyjs](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-env/#optionstargets-uglify).

Be great to see a repo or a Gist.